# Random number same in different processes

Tags: c#, random

I am using the following code to generate a unique Application InstanceID for logging.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Random rnd = new Random();

    instanceID = rnd.Next(100000, 999999);

    /// ...
}
```

my App starts with a windowsserver as different services (with nssm) 2 and more Times with different Parameters.
My Problem: if they start at the same time (same second), instanzID is the same, if 1 or more second difference instanzID is different.
How can i avoid this?

Comment: *"to generate a unique Application InstanceID"* - The semantics are important.  "Random" and "unique" are two very different things.  Perhaps use a `Guid` instead?

Comment: Thank you, i changed to Guid.NewGuid and will test it next time

Answer (score 2):

Well, `Random` is **not** *thread safe* (you've mentioned "server as different services"), that's why let each thread has its own `Random` instance:

```
private static ThreadLocal<Random> MyRandom = ...
```

Since we don't want all these instances generate the *same* sequences, let's provide an *entropy source*, we can do it with a help of `RNGCryptoServiceProvider`:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Threading;

...  

private static ThreadLocal<Random> MyRandom = new ThreadLocal<Random>(() => {
  int seed;

  using (RNGCryptoServiceProvider provider = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider()) {
    byte[] seedData = new byte[sizeof(int)];

    provider.GetBytes(seedData);

    seed = BitConverter.ToInt32(seedData, 0);
  }

  return new Random(seed);
});
```

Now, `MyRandom` is *thread safe* and each thread has *its own* (pseudo-)random sequence.

```
instanzID = MyRandom.Next(100000, 999999);
```

Comment: I don't think the problem is about using the same `Random` instance from different threads. The problem is that independent `Random` instances instantiated at the same time in different processes can be seeded with the same value. Seeding with `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` is a solution, but I don't think the `ThreadLocal` is relevant to the OP's question.

Comment: Yes, canton7 is right, i edited the question for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

By default the `Random` object uses the current time as the initial seed. To do what you want, just provide an `int` in the constructor as `Random rnd = new Random(seed)` where `seed` is the initial seed of the algorithm. As long as `seed` is the same for all of your `Random` objects, they will produce the same sequence of random numbers.